# How to diagnose "invalid opcode" when compiling?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a huge contract so isolating the cause will be very arduous manually. Is there any way to get an indication automatically of what might be causing an "invalid opcode" error?

Comment: What has that got to do with compilation? An `invalid opcode` error occurs during runtime. Generally speaking, every `assert` operation could cause this error, as well every access to an array at an illegal index (though this one possibly throws a `revert` error, not entirely sure).

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Opcode error occurs mostly when you are performing an mathematical operation and somewhere in the code **maybe you are dividing some number (variable) with 0**.

Maybe check your calculations to see if this is the case!

Hope this helps someone!